# How would I use an if else statement to make 2 datasets?

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm looking to take a dataset and look through one column to say:
"if this one variable == "true", then add the row to dataset1.  Else, add it to dataset2".

Comment: Can you show an example to test

Comment: Sure.  Lets say you had 2 rows.

```
 Col1     Col2
   0             1
   1             1
   0             0
   1             0
```
I would want to take all the rows in which Col1 == 1 and put it into a data set and put all rows where Col1==0 and put it in another dataset

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `subset`

```
df1 <- subset(df_full, Col1 == 1)
df0 <- subset(df_full, Col1 == 0)
```

Or with `split` into a `list`

```
lst1 <- split(df_full, df_full$Col1)
```